# Lagrange dual function for multivariable optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I wish to apply the duality theorem to the optimization problem:
$$\text{minimize}~~s$$
$$\text{subject to}~~g_j(x)\leq{s},~~\text{for all}~~j=1,...,r,~~x\in{X},~~s\in{\mathbb{R}},$$
where $X\subseteq{\mathbb{R}^n}$ is a nonempty convex set, and $g_j:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R},~j=1,...,r$ are convex functions. 
I want to use the result of this optimization problem for showing that a set of strict inequalities $g_j(x)<0$ (for all $j=1,...,r$) has no solution within the set $X$ if and only if there exists a vector $\nu\in\mathbb{R}^r$ such that:
$$\nu\geq0,~~\sum_{j=1}^r\nu_j=1,~~\langle\nu,g(x)\rangle\geq0~~\text{for all}~x\in{X},$$
and $g(x)=[g_1(x),...,g_r(x)]'$.
From my understanding, both $s$ and $x$ are the optimization variables and the Lagrange dual function should be formed using both of them. I wrote:
$$g(\mu,\lambda)=\inf\limits_{s\in\mathbb{R},~x\in{X}}\{s+\sum_{j=1}^r\mu_j(g_j(x)-s)\}.$$
When I take derivative w.r.t $x$, I end up with $\sum_{j=1}^{r}\mu_j\nabla{g_j}(x)=0$. When I take derivative w.r.t $s$, I get $\sum_{j=1}^r\mu_j=1$. After this point, I don't know what to do with the derivatives that I have.
1- I do not know if I am doing the right thing for the dual function or not. 
2- Also, I would appreciate some explanations on how to mathematically relate this dual problem to the problem related to the existence of $\nu$.

**Note: Intuitively, the constraint $\langle\nu,g(x)\rangle\geq0~~\text{for all}~x\in{X}$ dictates that at least of one $g_j(x)$ must be strictly positive. This is in contradiction with the set of strict inequalities $g_j(x)<0~~\text{for all}~x\in{X}$. However, I still wish to know how to apply the dual theorem to the optimization problem I mentioned.**